# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter3 : Why is my test failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If anyone could help me figure out why my test test is failing it would be a big help! I thought I was following each step perfectly but the `$ rails test` command results in Failure! I've retraced all of my steps and made sure there are no typos. I'm currently running the `$rails test` command in a branch, and using Cloud 9, a cloud developing environment.

**Static Pages Controller**:

```
    require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    puts response.body
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}", response.body
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    puts response.body
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}", response.body
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    puts response.body
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}", response.body
  end

end
```

**About.html.erb**:

```
<% provide(:title, "About") %>
<h1>About</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/"><em>Ruby on Rails Tutorial</em></a> is a 
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book">book</a> and
  <a href="http://www.screencasts.railstutorial.org/"> screencast series</a> 
  to teach web development with 
  <a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>.
  This is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

**Home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> sample application.
</p>
```

**Application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the same failure message for the About, Home, and Help tests. I added response.body at following the advice of some commenters.

**Failure Message**

```
F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:26]:
<h1>About</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/"><em>Ruby on Rails
  Tutorial</em></a> is a
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book">book</a> and
  <a href="http://screencasts.railstutorial.org/">screencast series</a>
  to teach web development with
  <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>.
  This is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
.
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `method': undefined method `test_should_get_about' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `format_rerun_snippet'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:23:in `record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:786:in `block in record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:785:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:785:in `record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:334:in `run_one_method'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:347:in `with_info_handler'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:319:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How does your help.html.erb look like?

Comment: <% provide(:title, "Help") %>
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
  Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help pages</a>. 
  To get help on this sample app, see the <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book"><em>Ruby on Rails Tutorial</em> book</a>.
</p>

Comment: The first thing you should do is see what the actual output is. Try `assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}", response.body`. Adding the second param should output the full response being tested by your assertion.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately this did not work

Comment: Add `puts page.body` after `get static_pages_help_url` and show us the response. It should give a clue what is being returned there.

Comment: Ok, @Magnuss I added the `puts page.body` and here's the result: `E

Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x0000000480cf10>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>' `   I'm not sure if it matters but the terminal is not currently not in the main branch

Comment: As @mahemoff pointed out we need to figure out what response are you getting. Change `puts page.body` to `puts response.body` and see if you get the full response instead. And put that line inside the `help` test after the `get ...` line.

Comment: It says `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in method': undefined method test_should_get_about' for class Minitest::Result' (NameError)`

Comment: Seems that you have changed something else. The error is unrelated. All I needed you to do is add ‘puts response.body’ after ‘get stattic_pages_help_url’. :)

Comment: I've updated the code so you can see where I put response.body and added a more detailed error message at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a layout error. Your assertion is checking for a string like "About | Site Name", but your output doesn't include a title tag, it's only showing a body and not anything from application.html.erb.

You need to ensure your controller is rendering your view using the layout defined in application.html.erb (this happens by default, but maybe something is misconfigured or your controller is rendering with something like `layout: false`).

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up about layouts and make sure your actions are using the default layout